# Split Pandas Dataframe With Equal Amount of Rows for each Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

This is for a machine learning project. 
I have a CSV file which I have read in as a Pandas dataframe. The CSV looks like this:

```
id,label
f38a6374c348f90b587e046aac6079959adf3835,0
c18f2d887b7ae4f6742ee445113fa1aef383ed77,1
755db6279dae599ebb4d39a9123cce439965282d,0
bc3f0c64fb968ff4a8bd33af6971ecae77c75e08,0
068aba587a4950175d04c680d38943fd488d6a9d,0
acfe80838488fae3c89bd21ade75be5c34e66be7,0
a24ce148f6ffa7ef8eefb4efb12ebffe8dd700da,1
7f6ccae485af121e0b6ee733022e226ee6b0c65f,1
559e55a64c9ba828f700e948f6886f4cea919261,0
8eaaa7a400aa79d36c2440a4aa101cc14256cda4,0
...
[220025 rows x 2 columns]
```

I have decreased the sample size  and equalized the data, so that I have a dataframe with 60,000 rows; 30,000 rows with label 1 and label 0. I now want to split the dataframe into two with one dataframe having 50,000 rows, and the other having 10,000, but I want each dataframe to have an equal amount of rows with label 1 and label 0.

There are some longer solutions, such as splitting the dataframe, then using `.frac()` to make two dataframes then merging alternate ones, but that is unnecessarily complex.

Is there any method to split the dataframe with equal amounts of rows for each label, but a different amount of total rows in each dataframe?

Here is the code I have used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random

df = pd.read_csv("../input/histopathologic-cancer-detection/train_labels.csv")

ones_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 1, :]
num_ones = len(ones_subset)

zeros_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 0, :]
sampled_zeros = zeros_subset.sample(num_ones)

print(num_ones)
print(sampled_zeros)

df = pd.concat([ones_subset, sampled_zeros], ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby("label").sample(30000).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `sklearn` + `stratify`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.16, random_state=19, stratify=df['label'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What should I input for `x` and `y`?

Comment: @DapperDuck usually x = df.drop('label'); y =df['label']

Comment: I tried this and I get this error message: `KeyError: "['label'] not found in axis"`. I ran `print(df.columns)` and this is the output:`Index(['id', 'label'], dtype='object')`. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @DapperDuck AH  it should be x = df.drop('label',axis=1); y =df['label']

Comment: Yes, just figured it out and was about to add this comment. It worked with: `x = df.drop(columns ="label")`